# Is it possible to manipulate an object on the Firebase server when one of its properties has been set to a specific value?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a situation where I have two clients that connect to the same firebase node and then communicate back and forth through that channel. When a client connects it creates the client(X)connected attribute and sets it to true, and when it disconnects it sets it to false. It sort of looks like the below structure, when both clients have connected.

```
- fbnode-123-456 (this is a uuid that both clients know before connecting)
   - clientAconnected: true
   - clientBconnected: true
```

Now what I would like to happen is that when both client's have disconnected and their connected values are both set to false the containing node, in the above example "fbnode-123-456", is also deleted.

The problem is that since at this point both clients are disconnected neither can remove that node. Is there a way to put a "rule" on the server to check those values on write/update and remove the node if both are false, or perhaps some other way that I am not thinking of?

I'd like to avoid using an external server app to monitor the connections and do the removing (by avoid I mean, I cannot do that in this circumstance).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

1. have the last client to disconnect remove whatever node you want to get rid of in your [`onDisconnect` handler](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/ondisconnect/)
2. instead of keeping a boolean to indicate whether a client is connected, *only* store connected clients. So:

   ```
   fbnode-123-456
       connectedClients
         clientA
         clientB
   ```

   when both clientA and clientB nodes disappear, Firebase will automatically clear up the `connectedClients` and `fbnode-123-456` nodes above them (if they're empty).